# Force Bitbucket Commit to be associated to JIRA Ticket by Comment Formatting

Tags: bitbucket, jira, git-commit, pre-commit-hook

The exact need is to force all commits into Bitbucket to be linked to a JIRA ticket.

I have does this before on Subversion by creating a commit hook that looked for the JIRA ticket in the commit text, but I don't want this solution to be necessarily constrained to that prior experience.

Does Bitbucket have a setting somewhere to force association for all commits against Jira tickets? If not - does it have a mechanism for enforce commit comment quality (some sort of hook or regex)? If not - does GIT have something that we can use for this purpose?

The imagined solution is (but not limited to being) a commit hook that fails the commit if the comment text does not contain a leading JIRA ticket, followed by a colon, followed by some commit text, such that:

```
git commit -m "foo"
```

fails and

```
git commit -m "PRJ-9327: foo"
```

commits...

Comment: The feature is out of beta now (https://bitbucket.org/site/master/issues/5658/option-to-reject-commits-without-an-issue#comment-35965158): I have edited the answer to reflect that.

Comment: By the way, it is "Jira", not "JIRA". "Jira" is not an acronym.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The [BitBucket issue 5658](https://bitbucket.org/site/master/issues/5658/option-to-reject-commits-without-an-issue) just got implemented today (April 13th, 2017)

> Option to reject commits without an issue key in their message
>
> This feature is now available to all users via the repository settings "`links`" page
>
> The pre-receive hook that rejects pushes when any commit does not have a valid issue key in its message.
> The current implementation relies on the per-repository "`Links`" setting to determine what a valid issue key looks like. This gives us the ability to validate against Jira, Bitbucket Issues, Connect add-ons, and any configured custom Links.

So you don't need for a third-party plugin anymore.

[image: Link]

Answer (score 1):

## Update (14 April 2017)

It looks like this feature has been integrated to the JIRA mainline and should be released soon. See [VonC's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43401943/4494577) for details.

## Original answer

There is a number of plugins for Bitbucket that can do this. For example [Commit Policy Plugin for Bitbucket](https://marketplace.atlassian.com/plugins/com.midori.bitbucket.plugin.commitpolicy/server/overview) (free)

Disclosure: I'm not in any way connected to the team behind the plugin I mentioned.